# Using canvas.drawImage to draw .png image. the image is always blur

Tags: flutter, canvas

Firstly I load the image from asset:

```dart
  Future<Null> init() async {
    final ByteData data =
        await rootBundle.load('assets/images/shapes_delete.png');
     image = await loadImage(Uint8List.view(data.buffer));
}
  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(Uint8List img) async {
    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {
      return completer.complete(img);
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
```

then using canvas to draw the image:

```
         canvas.drawImage(
           image,
            Offset(boundRect.right ,
                boundRect.top),
            paint);
```

But I always get the blur image(you can see the delete button is blur). I tried to set bounds to the image, but I didn't find such a method.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that simply what the image's resolution is like?

Comment: see `Paint.filterQuality`

Comment: @lvo the png image resolution is 72px*72px, it looks normal if I open it with image App in my computer. I'm just looking for some methods to set limited width and height to the image

Comment: @pskinkI set **paint.filterQuality = FilterQuality.high**, it sees better now. But not prefect. the image is still a little blur.  are there any methods I can set width and height to the image. so if the image  is 72px*72px, then I set the boundary rect to 54*54px, then It will be absolutely clear

Comment: use `drawImageRect` then (or even better top level `paintImage` function)

Comment: @pskink thanks you, I tried `paintImage(
    rect: Rect.fromLTWH(
        boundRect.right,
        boundRect.top,
        54,
        54,
    image:image,
    canvas: canvas);`
 this method allows me to give the boundary rect to the image. you are saving my time

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this may work, you need diff resolution image

Comment: I am doing the same, it's still blur if I only use 3.0x image